# Converting float to NSNumber

Tags: ios

I am missing something basic, here.  Must have forgotten it.  But basically, I have the following code the purpose  take an NSNumber, convert it to float, multiply it by 2 and return the result to an NSNumber.   I get an error on the last step, and am stumped.  What should I do there.

```
NSNumber *testNSNumber = [[[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:200.0f] autorelease];
float myfloatvalue = [testNSNumber  floatValue] * -2;
NSLog(@" Test float value %1.2f \n\n",myfloatvalue);
[testNSNumber floatValue:myfloatvalue];  // error here is floatValue is not found
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The method `floatValue` of `NSNumber` does not take parameters. If you would like to set a new float number, you need to re-assign `testNSNumber`, because `NSNumber` does not have a mutable counterpart:

```
testNSNumber = @(myfloatvalue); // The new syntax
```

or

```
testNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: myfloatvalue]; // The old syntax
```

Comment: why not to use @(myfloatvalue)?

Comment: @JulianKról Thanks! This answer has been written more than a year before the `@(...)` syntax was introduced. I updated it to reflect the new syntax.

Comment: much better now :) I know that it is a problem to keep posted answers fresh personally but as a community we can achieve this.

Answer (score 16):

Swift 3.0:

```
let testNSNumber: NSNumber = NSNumber(value: myfloatvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0 version:

```
let testNSNumber: NSNumber = NSNumber(float: myfloatvalue)
```